# Disable Noise Cancellation

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I'm a Ubuntu 18.04 user.

I have added this line `load-module module-echo-cancel` and ran commands `pulseaudio -k` and `pulseaudio --start` in my system to avoid echo, but echo is not cancelled instead voice is breaking, during calls people I can't hear others voice completely or people on the other hand cannot able to completely hear my voice.
How can I remove this from my system now?

If I remove that line I added, system cannot able to recognize any mic.
In settings-> Input it shows microphone, but when I try to join any calls it says you don't have any mic.

How can I bring back my system into normal?

Comment: Really your mic is *not* recognized when removing the line (i.e., not visible in Settings - sound)? Or do you have no audio from it?

Comment: In settings-> Input it shows microphone, but when I try to join any calls it says you don't have any mic

Comment: Might be relevant info, so you want to add that to your question (use "edit"). Also provide relevant hardware information.